# How to get common sequence(s) of two arrays? Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, set-theory

Return common longest sequence(s) of array elements of both arrays. Sequence, including duplicates and located anywhere within the array.

For example I want to retrieve the subset `[2,2,3]`, which is the common sequence of `arr1` and `arr2` using minimal amount of code (for example with set operations) ideally without converting the `ints` to `strings`

```
arr1 = [1,2,2,3,4]
arr2 = [5,2,2,3,6]
# common subset sequence is [2,2,3]

arr1 = [2,2,3,3,5]
arr1 = [3,3,2,2,5]
# common sequences are [2,2] [3,3]
```

Comment: Can you post what you have actually tried? There are a lot of cases not covered by your current question. Such as: What constitutes a "sequence" is it 2 or more; 3 or more?  What is the anticipation for multiple patterns eg. `arr1 = [1,2,2,3,4,7,7,6,2]` and `arr2 = [5,2,2,3,6,7,7,6,2,]`? What happens if the sequences are the same but in different locations `[1,2,2,3,4]` and `[5,6,2,2,3]`? etc.

Comment: Well i thought it was pretty straight forward. Find a common sequence of array elements anywhere in the either array. The example i created was only to show an example. I think you your over analyzing the term "sequence". What I mean by sequence is exact pattern of elements (any where in either array) ...For the example you given, Im only interested in [2,2,3] excluding the rest of the array

Comment: I think your over analyzing the word sequence. if i have [1,2,3,4] and [1,2,3,4] the only sequence you are interested in is [1,2,3,4] not [1] or [1,2] or [1,2,3] but simply "the longest" sequence if you need an exact definition. As for the case you just inputted I realized that there can be multiple sequences and for those cases the solution should just return an array of the sequences.

Comment: Then add these options to your question so we can formulate a single answer to handle these cases because it seems that `[1,1,2,2,3,3,]` and its reverse should return either `[[1,1],[2,2],[3,3]]` or `[[3,3,],[2,2],[1,1]]` depending upon precedence. Also `[1,2,2,5]` and `[1,2,2,2,5]` is that `[[1,2,2],[2,5]]` or `[[1,2],[2,2,5]]`?

Comment: @engineersmnky, the OP wants to return the “common longest sequence(s) of array elements of both arrays”. In your example the longest common sequence has length 5 and there is only one common sequence of that length, so `[[1,2,2,2,5]]` is returned. Also, because sequences are ordered I didn’t consider reverse orders (but of course that would not be diffficult). That is my interpretation anyway

Comment: @CarySwoveland *"What I mean by sequence is exact pattern of elements (any where in either array)"* And if you look at the definition of "longest" provided in comment to is simply provides that a continuous sequence not be divided not that separate sequences cannot be of different lengths. That was my only point. I would certainly concede had there been examples of input and output values that touch on such cases.

Comment: @engineersmnky, I see your point. horror_fan, can you edit to clarify?

Comment: Does my answer provide the information you want (i.e., have I interpreted the question correctly?)

Answer (score 0):

If `n` is the size of the smaller of the two arrays, the following method first computes all sequences of length `n` for each array and then determines those sequences in the first array that also appear in the second array. The number of such common sequences is clearly zero or one (the latter because at least one of the arrays is of size `n`). If there is one common sequence of length `n` we return an array containing that single sequence and we are finished.

If there are no common sequences of length `n` we repeat the procedure for sequences of length `n - 1`. If an array of the common sequences of length `n - 1` is non-empty we return that array and are finished; else we repeat for sequences of length `n - 2`, and so on. `nil` is returned if there are no common sequences of length `1`.

**Code**

```
def longest_common_sequences(arr1, arr2)
  [arr1.size, arr2.size].min.downto(0).each do |n|
    break nil if n.zero? 
    common = sequences_by_length(arr1, n) & sequences_by_length(arr2, n)
    break common unless common.empty?
  end         
end

def sequences_by_length(arr, n)
  arr.each_cons(n).to_a
end
```

**Examples**

```
longest_common_sequences [1,2,2,3,4], [5,2,2,3,6]
   #=> [[2, 2, 3]]

longest_common_sequences [2,2,3,3,5], [3,3,2,2,5]
  #=> [[2, 2], [3, 3]]

longest_common_sequences [1,2,3], [4,5,6]
  #=> nil
```

**Explanation**

I've added `puts` statements to the body of `longest_common_sequences` to illustrate the calculations performed by the method for the second example above.

```
arr1 = [2,2,3,3,5]
arr2 = [3,3,2,2,5]

t = [arr1.size, arr2.size].min
puts "[arr1.size, arr2.size].min = #{t}"
t.downto(0).each do |n|
  puts "n = #{n}"
  puts "break nil as #{n}.zero? #=> true" if n.zero?
  break nil if n.zero? 
  common = sequences_by_length(arr1, n) & sequences_by_length(arr2, n)
  puts "common = #{common}"
  break common unless common.empty?
end         

def sequences_by_length(arr, n)
  puts "  generate sequences of length #{n} for arr = #{arr}"
  a = arr.each_cons(n).to_a
  puts "  returning #{a}"
  a
end
```

prints

```
n = 5
  generate sequences of length 5 for arr = [2, 2, 3, 3, 5]
  returning [[2, 2, 3, 3, 5]]
  generate sequences of length 5 for arr = [3, 3, 2, 2, 5]
  returning [[3, 3, 2, 2, 5]]
common = []
n = 4
  generate sequences of length 4 for arr = [2, 2, 3, 3, 5]
  returning [[2, 2, 3, 3], [2, 3, 3, 5]]
  generate sequences of length 4 for arr = [3, 3, 2, 2, 5]
  returning [[3, 3, 2, 2], [3, 2, 2, 5]]
common = []
n = 3
  generate sequences of length 3 for arr = [2, 2, 3, 3, 5]
  returning [[2, 2, 3], [2, 3, 3], [3, 3, 5]]
  generate sequences of length 3 for arr = [3, 3, 2, 2, 5]
  returning [[3, 3, 2], [3, 2, 2], [2, 2, 5]]
common = []
n = 2
  generate sequences of length 2 for arr = [2, 2, 3, 3, 5]
  returning [[2, 2], [2, 3], [3, 3], [3, 5]]
  generate sequences of length 2 for arr = [3, 3, 2, 2, 5]
  returning [[3, 3], [3, 2], [2, 2], [2, 5]]
common = [[2, 2], [3, 3]]
```

As `common.empty? #=> false`, `[[2, 2], [3, 3]]` is returned.

Comment: Cary I just still have so many unanswered questions. For example `[2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` and `[2, 3, 4, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]` returns `[[2,2,2,3,4]]` but what about `[1,2,3,4]` which is an available pattern in `a` and listed in `b`? There are just not enough specifications provided to determine the bounds as to what is an answer. I read the comment regarding "longest" meant that `[1,2,3,4]` would not become `[[1,2],[3,4]]` not that only the longest pattern mattered